Property of a sequence on $\mathbb Q[\sqrt m~]$
Given that $a_{1} = \sqrt m$ in which $m$ is a integer that is not the square of any integer. And $$a_{n+1}=\frac{[a_{n}]}{\{a_{n}\}}$$where $[~ ]$ and $\{~ \}$ respectively represent the integer part and the decimal part of a number.
The problem is that for what kind of $m$ (if there exists) the sequence will finally be stable, to say, $a_n=c$, for any  $n>N$.
what I've tried is solving the equation$$k+r=\frac{k}{r}$$to get $$r=\frac{-k + \sqrt {k^2-4k}}{2} or\frac{-k-\sqrt {k^2-4k}}{2}.$$ By noting that $\frac{\sqrt {k^2-4k}}{\sqrt m}$ should be rational, to say $\frac{p}{q}$. I conclude that
$$k=\frac{4q^2}{mp^2-q^2}$$So $mp^2-q^2$ can only be $1$, $2$ or $4$.
The analysis above gives that $-1$, $-2$ and $-4$ must be quadratic residue mod $m.$
However it is hard to give further conclusion...

Note that $0<r<1\le k$ (otherwise, sequence consists of rational numbers). But $(-k\pm\sqrt{k^2-4k})/2\not\in(0;1)$ for integer $k\ge1$. Thus the sequence doesn't stabilize
